# Angular unable to locate stylesheet warning

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have get a warning like this

> Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: D:\Angular\certification\Angular8Certification\https:\stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com\bootstrap\4.4.1\css\bootstrap.min.css

I am new to Angular. When I add CSS it did not apply. What is the reason and what should I want to do?

Here is my console
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**

This warning is caused by new update in polyfills.

Solution is:

1. Remove all bootstrap cdn links from index.html
2. Install bootstrap >
   `npm install bootstrap`
3. Next, go the angular.json file and add the paths of Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files to the styles and scripts arrays under the build target as follows:
   [image]
4. `ng serve --open` again.

**Result**

[image]

This solution worked for me.

Comment: It is not work for me...When I have done it navi bar disappear

Comment: @Samanthika Rajapaksa I've updated my answer, give a try....

Comment: @SamanthikaRajapaksa  , After tdoi9ng this, are you getting the same error or something else?  Can you put the screen shots of index.html, package.json, and angular.json.  ?   whole code lines of these files is preferred.

Comment: @SujalShah Do you know how to avoid the waring message if you really want to load css from CDN and do not include it to angular.json styles from local directory?

Comment: @DavidZencak you can import it as `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`  in your stylesheet instead

Comment: I solved my issue with post https://stackoverflow.com/a/78174079/2112736