# "WARNING Unable to locate stylesheet" after upgrading to Angular 16

Tags: angular, webpack

We recently upgraded from Angular 9 to 16, and I keep getting warnings about stylesheets not being found. The ones that are generating warnings are included in index.html:

```html
    <head>
      <!-- snip -->
      <base href="/">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/googleFont.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/blueprint-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/fonts/css/fm-icon-font.css" />
    </head>
```

This shows up in the Node console when I run `ng serve`:

```
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\css\googleFont.css    
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\css\blueprint-ui.css    
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css    
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\fonts\css\fm-icon-font.css
```

Similar warnings show up in the browser console:

```
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\css\googleFont.css
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\css\blueprint-ui.css
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css
polyfills.js:12 [webpack-dev-server] WARNING
Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\assets\fonts\css\fm-icon-font.css
```

Interestingly, these paths are wrong. The correct path is `C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\src\assets\css\filename.css`. Note the extra `src`.

The styles do seem to work on the page, so this is more an annoyance than anything else. I've tried changing the links to include the `src` part:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/assets/css/blueprint-ui.css">
```

This didn't work. The styles no longer showed up, and in fact the warnings changed to `Unable to locate stylesheet: C:\Developers\g3h-cucor-ui\src\assets\css\blueprint-ui.css`. This is extra weird, since that is the legitimate path to the file. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why are you adding styles within the index.html and not via workspace configuration?
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#extra-build-and-test-options

Comment: @SirOneOfMany I don't know why it was done that way; it was like that when I started on the project. But I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research on how webpack works and how paths are resolved there. It was done this way because people obviously did not know what they were doing

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue only occurred in the development environment (local). This was happening because my project, which ran fine on Angular 11, was migrated to Angular 12 and, when running locally with `ng serve`, the angular.json file was running the code with enabled optimization. Disabling optimization no longer triggered the warnings during execution.

[image]

I changed the attribute to false and the warnings stopped being displayed. My project also didn't have this "development" session of the build; I copied it from an angular.json of a new project created with the Angular CLI.